# Can't insert complex XML file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure like below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ComplexXml]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XmlString xml

    SET @XmlString = 
    '<ArrayOfSizeColorQuantityViewModel>
      <ProductId>012312</ProductId>
      <SizeColorQuantityViewModel>
        <ColorId>Red</ColorId>
        <SizeAndQuantities>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>S</SizeId>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>M</SizeId>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>L</SizeId>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>XL</SizeId>
            <Quantity>4</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
        </SizeAndQuantities>
      </SizeColorQuantityViewModel>

      <SizeColorQuantityViewModel>
        <ColorId>Blue</ColorId>
        <SizeAndQuantities>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>S</SizeId>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>M</SizeId>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>L</SizeId>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
          <SizeAndQuantity>
            <SizeId>XL</SizeId>
            <Quantity>4</Quantity>
          </SizeAndQuantity>
        </SizeAndQuantities>
      </SizeColorQuantityViewModel>
    </ArrayOfSizeColorQuantityViewModel>'

    INSERT INTO ProductSizeColor(ProductID, SizeID, ColorID, Quantity)
        SELECT
            SCQ.node.value('(../ProductId)[1]', 'bigint') as 'ProductID',
            SCQ.node.value('(ColorId)[1]', 'varchar(3)') as 'ColorID',
            SQ.i.value('(SizeId)[1]', 'varchar(3)') as 'SizeID',
            SQ.i.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int') as 'Quantity'
        FROM
            @XmlString.nodes('/ArrayOfSizeColorQuantityViewModel/SizeColorQuantityViewModel') as SCQ(node)
        CROSS APPLY 
            SCQ.node.nodes('/SizeAndQuantities/SizeAndQuantity') as SQ(i)
END
```

And I try to insert this complex XML data to table below:

**Table:** (3 foreign keys)

[image]

I don't know whether I have any problem with parse XML code or not?
If you don't mind could you please help me find it out?

Thanks for kind helping

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s OMG. I'll read it carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT
    SCQ.node.value('(../ProductId)[1]', 'bigint') as 'ProductID',
    SCQ.node.value('(ColorId)[1]', 'varchar(4)') as 'ColorID',
    SQ.i.value('(SizeId)[1]', 'varchar(3)') as 'SizeID',
    SQ.i.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int') as 'Quantity'
FROM
    @XmlString.nodes('/ArrayOfSizeColorQuantityViewModel/SizeColorQuantityViewModel') as SCQ(node)
CROSS APPLY 
    SCQ.node.nodes('SizeAndQuantities/SizeAndQuantity') as SQ(i)
```

I just removed a leading `/` from your second XPath (in the `CROSS APPLY`), and I also extended the length of the `ColorId` value to `varchar(4)` (to allow for "blue" to be shown properly).

Now I get this output from the `SELECT`:

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks for your kind helping :D